# When will the method acquireQueued of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer entry it's finally block?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

```
final boolean acquireQueued(final Node node, int arg) {
    boolean failed = true;
    try {
        boolean interrupted = false;
        for (;;) {
            final Node p = node.predecessor();
            if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                setHead(node);
                p.next = null; // help GC
                failed = false;
                return interrupted;
            }
            if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) && parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                interrupted = true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (failed)
            cancelAcquire(node);
    }
}
```

When I read the source code of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer of Jdk1.8,I think of the acquireQueued method of AbstractQueuedSynchronizer for a long time.On which condition,the invocation will entry the 'finally' block and the cancelAcquire method?Jumping out of the loop must be the 'return' logic,in which the 'failed' was set false.

Comment: I think you are not too sure of what `try-finally` block does. It means that this block of code in `finally` will always execute no matter how it exits `try` block, even if it is via `return` statement or uncaught exception. The only time `cancelAcquire()` is called is when the `try` block didn't reach the `failed = false;` line due to the `if` statement.

Comment: @jai it appears that the only way the `for` loop can exit is if it is returned at `return interrupted;`  which has `failed = false;` set before it.  Or am I missing that a RuntimeException may occur?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Now that you mentioned this, it does seems like the only way this can happen is when there is a `RuntimeException` in one of the methods.

Comment: Just like that the blocking thread was interrupted while blocking by the LockSupport#pack and threw an InterruptedException?

Comment: `InterruptedException` is a checked exception

Comment: @ScaryWombat The only unchecked Exception  I found in the method is the NullPointerException threw by the method Node#predecessor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `cancelAcquire()` would meet after `tryAcquire(arg)` throws an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

If the current thread racing for the lock is interrupted,then the if condition will hold true:

> if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) && parkAndCheckInterrupt())
>                   interrupted = true;

then code in finally block will be executed.

Otherwise, it will always be blocked until LockSupport.unpark method is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

When you override `tryAcquire()` maybe throw Error or Exception.
`acquireQueued()` mark with `final`.
Example class `ReentrantLock.FairSync` about `tryAcquire()` throw a `Error`

Answer (score 0):

`cancelAcquire` is primarily applied to the API in response to interrupts. for example:

```
    private void doAcquireInterruptibly(long arg)
        throws InterruptedException {
        final Node node = addWaiter(Node.EXCLUSIVE);
        boolean failed = true;
        try {
            for (;;) {
                final Node p = node.predecessor();
                if (p == head && tryAcquire(arg)) {
                    setHead(node);
                    p.next = null; // help GC
                    failed = false;
                    return;
                }
                if (shouldParkAfterFailedAcquire(p, node) &&
                    parkAndCheckInterrupt())
                     // sleep timeout or thread.interrupt(), then execute finally
                    throw new InterruptedException();
            }
        } finally {
            if (failed)
                cancelAcquire(node);
        }
    }
```